# Poll returns pollhup and pollerr if socket is bound to eth0 interface

Tags: c, sockets, client-server

I'm using a sample client program and server applications. Client code is from (https://github.com/nori0428/mod_websocket/blob/master/src/mod_websocket_socket.c#L19-L68) and server program is from (http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/12/c-socket-programming/). The client and socket program are working fine unless I bind the server socket to eth0 or eth1 n/w interface using SO_BINDTODEVICE. If I don't bind the server socket to a specific n/w interface or if I bind the server socket to loopback ip, the client server program is working. But if I bind to eth0/eth1, poll fails with pollhup and pollerr. The errno returns as connection refused. But the server is running and listening in the particular interface.
Queries,
I need to limit the server socket to accept data from a particular interface alone. How do I do that?
Why is that if I bind the server socket to eth0/eth1, the client fails with connection refused, but if I bind the server socket to loopback ip, the client/server program works.

Answer (score 0):

the loopback data route does not go through the eth/0 nor eth/1

Therefore if you bind to those devices, then cannot communicate via loopback.

There is really no reason to bind to those devices, even when the server/client are on different machines.

The 'bind to device' is only really useful when working with a network server that has many connections to the  internet and you want to distribute the traffic load

much easier to just bind to a 'port' (a mythical device) and let the communication protocol handle the detail of exactly which hardware I.O is actually used.

Comment: I need to restrict the server socket accept connections from particular network interface, how can I do that?